# Does Xamarin Support ASLR for iOS and Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

As I understand it iOS has supported Address Space Layout Randomisation (ASLR) since iOS 4.3 and Android since 4.0.

Is this functionality supported by Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

On `xamarin-macios`, PIE is enabled by default during the app's AOT process, unless you disable it via `mtouch`:

```
{ "pie:", "Enable (default) or disable PIE (Position Independent Executable).", v => { app.EnablePie = ParseBool (v, "pie"); }},
```

On `xamarin-android`, AOT'ing the app's assemblies is not the default, so PIE means nothing to the managed/IL code.

As for the `mono` runtime, the make file enables `-pie` / `-fPIE` by default.

But in the end, none of that matters to security professionals as you should be using tools like `readelf` to verify the binaries that you are publishing are `DYN` enabled.